# Probability of real roots(short way)

Tags: probability

Each coefficient in the equation $ax^2+bx+c$ is determined by throwing an ordinary dice. Find the probability that the given equation will have real roots?
I counted the cases which fulfill D(discriminant) greater than zero, but that turned into a long method.

Is there an elegant short way to do this question?

Comment: *How* is each coefficient determined according to the die result? Also, is the die an ordinary, six sided one with numbers from $1$ to $6$ or is it arbitrarily sized? Are the coefficients $a,b,c$ real?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Yes the die is an ordinary six sided one and as the numbers on the dice are from 1to 6 do a,b,c must be real

Comment: It seems you need to consider cases $b  \leq 2 \sqrt{ac}$ and $b \geq 2 \sqrt{ac}$.

Comment: If discriminant$ b^2-4ac > 0 $then both the condition s you gave are satisfied.

Comment: @user90596: that's exactly what I wrote

Comment: If $D=0$ (e.g. $a=c=1, b=2$) you get a double real root

Comment: Oh yes , sorry I used it while solving but some how forgot all about it now,

Comment: But is there a way to do it without counting cases

Comment: Yeah, it does, thanks